# Kafka output binding sslkeypassword

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, azure-functions, ssl-certificate

I am using a kafka trigger that triggers a function and executes some code, after it has finished this code it will send a new event to return it's status using a kafka output binding.

In the kafka trigger I can use the %SslKeyPassword% notation to get the password for the certificate. However in the output binding this gives me an ssl error.

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter eventData after function returned:. Confluent.Kafka: ssl.key.location: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib.
```

When I put in the password hardcoded in the attribute it works perfectly however when trying to fetch it from local.settings.json it won't work.